# Как повернуть изображение

Tags: java, android

Есть Bitmap, как можно его перевернуть на 90 градусов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(angle);
      return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

[гугли сам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015372/how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-90-degrees/16219591#16219591)  простые вопросы, перед тем как спрашивать.

Comment: спасибо, я гуглил, как повенуть изображение android. не знал как это сделать на английском.

Comment: Может быть стоит присмотрется к 1С? там всё на великом-могучем.

Comment: argamidon жжет напалмом.    
@YeldosTanikin, без знания английского в программировании делать нечего.

Comment: Я сейчас занимаюсь английским.

Comment: @argamidon Дублирование информации из интернета в виде вопроса-ответа на SO - совершенно нормальная практика. Вопрос посмотрели 90 раз за сутки, он вполне актуален. А ваш тролинг неуместен.

Comment: **Помогите с этим**   --    http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477079/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4